# MS-Access: join tables, group records by a field taking only the first record in case of equal values and order the result by another field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table called `Materials` in MS Access (obviously simplified for question purposes):

| ID | Name | DescriptionNum | SpecificWeight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | - | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Ordinary steel | 1 | 7.85 |
| 2 | 1.1730 | 14 | 7.85 |
| 3 | 1.2083 | 15 | 7.85 |
| 4 | 1.2312 | 19 | 7.8 |
| 5 | 1730 | 14 | 7.85 |
| 6 | 2312 | 19 | 7.85 |

and another table `MatForTool` containing just the IDs of the Materials for a certain application (Tool in our case):

| ID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

What I need to achieve is to get all the fields of the materials based on the IDs appearing in `MatForTool` but also have them grouped by `DescriptionNum`; if there are other records with equal values for `DescriptionNum`, we'll always take the first one.
Furthermore, the result should be ordered by `ID`.

In practice, given the previous example tables, I want to obtain the following result:

| ID | Name | DescriptionNum | SpecificWeight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1.1730 | 14 | 7.85 |
| 3 | 1.2083 | 15 | 7.85 |
| 4 | 1.2312 | 19 | 7.8 |

**Constraints**: I cannot change the structure of the database and/or the data it contains.

In pseudo-query language (I am not an SQL expert at all), I would say:
"*Select all the fields in `Materials` as long as their `ID` appears in `MatForTool`, group them by `DescriptionNum`, if there are repeated values of `DescriptionNum` take the first record and order everything by `ID`.*"

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT
   FIRST(Materials.ID) AS ID, 
   FIRST(Materials.Material) AS Material,
   Materials.DescriptionNum,
   FIRST(Materials.SpecificWeight) AS SpecificWeight
FROM Materials INNER JOIN MatForTool ON Materials.ID = MatForTool.ID
GROUP BY Materials.DescriptionNum;
```

which kind of works but of course does not order by `ID`.

If I try to add the clause `ORDER BY Materials.ID`, MS Access complains with the following error:

"*Your query does not include the specified expression 'Materials.ID' as part of an aggregate function.*"

Of course, I have searched on the Internet for a solution to my problem but I was not able to find one, therefore here I am asking for help.

P.S.: If possible, I would also like to avoid specifying all the fields; I'd like to be able to say something like 'FIRST(*)' meaning 'take the first of everything'.

P.P.S.: I know `FIRST` is specific to Microsoft, hence it's non-portable but that's not a problem in my domain. Anyway, if there is a portable solution, it would be even better.

Thanks in advance to anyone who'll take the time to help.

Comment: You can make that error go away by adding Materials.ID to the GROUP BY: "GROUP BY Materials.DescriptionNum, Materials.ID". However, that will create more groups if there are multiple Materials.ID values for a given Materials.DescriptionNum.

Alternatively, you could leave the query as-is and use it as the record source for another query where you impose the desired order.

I also wonder about your use of FIRST: my interpretation of the documentation tells me it doesn't operate on groups, just entire results sets. I could be wrong.

Comment: @nicomp thank you very much for your help.
Yes, the documentation of FIRST is not very clear but it seems to do what I need, i.e. the result is correct: for each field where it is applied it returns the value the field has on the first record of each group (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71834628/getting-first-row-of-each-group-with-sql-in-microsoft-access).
Thanks to your suggestion, I've combined my first "SELECT" with another one with the ORDER BY and it worked as I wanted:
SELECT * FROM (my previous query as it was) ORDER BY ID;
Thank you very much.

Comment: Nice! Congratulations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @nicomp, I've tried the following and it worked:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
     FIRST(Materials.ID) AS ID, 
     FIRST(Materials.Material) AS Material,
     Materials.DescriptionNum,
     FIRST(Materials.SpecificWeight) AS SpecificWeight
     FROM Materials INNER JOIN MatForTool ON Materials.ID = MatForTool.ID
     GROUP BY Materials.Description
) ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Have in mind, though, that `FIRST` may not return _the first_ (minimum) but rather _any_ (which sometimes is the first).

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean. Fortunately, in my case, it is OK to have the _first_ even if it is not the _minimum_.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DISTINCT to get only unique (first) record of the result of each matching joined column. Try this query below:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT Materials.ID AS ID, 
   Materials.Name AS Material,
   Materials.DescriptionNum,
   Materials.SpecificWeight AS SpecificWeight
FROM Materials INNER JOIN MatForTool ON Materials.ID = MatForTool.ID
GROUP BY Materials.ID, Materials.DescriptionNum;
```

Here is the link for [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3d391/1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, despite your SQL Fiddle example works, I have tried it with MS-Access and it does not work. When I try to run the query I get the error message "Your query does not include the specified expression 'ID' as part of an aggregate function."
Probably MS-Access does not support such a query.

Comment: Maybe due to the database structure difference, try to add Materials.ID in the `GROUP BY` clause